# How to get text out of a Word document using Active Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word, activex, activeqt

I have several Word documents and I need the text out of them in my programm, to make my specific pdf file out of it. At the moment i have following code which allows me to show the word document, but i need the plain text.

```
QAxWidget* WordDocument=new QAxWidget ("Word.Document", this-> ui-> textEdit);
WordDocument-> setGeometry (QRect (10, 10, 621, 471));
WordDocument->setControl ("C:\\Users\\user6\\Desktop\\Optimierung des Verteilerbaus.docx");
WordDocument-> show ();
```

How can I get the text out of it?

Comment: [This](http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/) can be run on the `WordDocument` object to iterate the paragraphs and extract text.

Comment: Use `QAxBase::dynamicCall` to call methods on the document, iterate paragraphs, and get the text out.